# How to convert/map posted nested JSON data to SQLAlchemy models

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, entity-relationship

I am trying to POST data in postman which is nested with lists, am having a One-to-One relationship of models. How can I structure my models with `SQLAlchemy`

This is how I want to `POST` my data :

```
{
  "name" : "Netherlands tour",
  "description" : "This is an amazing tour .....",
  "price": 2.339393,
  "capacity": 2,
  "destinations" :[
    {
      "location": " location one ",
      "danger_type" : "low"
    },
    {
      "location": " location two ",
      "danger_type" : "medium"
    },
  ]
  "availabledates" :[
    
      {"date_" : "2020-08-05"},
      {"date_" : "2020-04-02"}
    
  ]
}
```

But I don't know whats the best approach to do this with `SQLAlchemy`.

Below are my models :

```
class TourPackages(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'tourpackage'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(50))
    description = db.Column(db.TEXT)
    price = db.Column(db.Float)
    destination_id = db.relationship('Destinations', backref='destination_id')
    available_date_id = db.relationship('AvailableDates', backref='available_date_id')
    capacity = db.Column(db.Integer)
    created_on = db.Column(db.DateTime(), default=datetime.utcnow)




class Destinations(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'destinations'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    tour_Packages = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('tourpackage.id'))
    location = db.Column(db.String(50))
    danger_type = db.Column(db.String(50))


class AvailableDates(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'availabledates'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    date_ = db.Column(db.String(50))
    tour_date = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('tourpackage.id'))
```

What is the best practice to POST data with such a Nested json ?

Comment: If you use flask then you can use https://flask-restful.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: Consider using a better title. "How to convert/map posted JSON to SQLAlchemy models" seems like a closer fit to what you are asking here.

Comment: Thanks @Tomalak,, done editting

Comment: You could use [marshmallow](https://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) and [flask-marshmallow](https://flask-marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). It's based on [webargs](https://webargs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) and supports sqlalchemy through [marshmallow-sqlalchemy](https://marshmallow-sqlalchemy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). In my opinion a very modern way to provide APIs. It offers a lot of possibilities to adapt the output to your needs. I prefer it to flask-RESTful.